# Application Cache Manifest with Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2, cache-manifest

I am trying to make a basic application that would make my index.html file run offline - when no internet is available.  I am using Google App Engine, Webapp2 and Jinja2.  Would you suggest a better framework for an offline website / webapp.

When I run this application I get this console error:

```
Creating Application Cache with manifest http://localhost:9080/static/cache.manifest localhost/:1
Application Cache Checking event localhost/:1
Application Cache Downloading event localhost/:1
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 1) http://localhost:9080/index.html localhost/:1
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (404) http://localhost:9080/index.html
```

---

I used the following:

**Files**

```
static/cache.manifest
main.py
index.html
app.yaml
```

**main.py**

```
import os, webapp2, jinja2

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class Home(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.write(template.render())

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', Home),
                              ], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="/static/cache.manifest">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello World
    </body>
</html>
```

**cache.manifest**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
/index.html
```

**app.yaml**

```
application: formetoteston
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: /static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  expiration: "0m"

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  I needed to add the proper URL handlers in app.yaml.  Except I moved my index.html to /static.

```
application: formetoteston
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: static/(cache.manifest)
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: static/cache.manifest
  upload: static/(cache.manifest)

- url: static/(.*)
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"

- name: jinja2
  version: "2.6"
```